# Bot Framework - "Unable to find a QnA Maker Service with Knowledge Base ID..." Error

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have a curious issue/non-issue with my Faq QnAMaker knowledgebase configuration.

When I send a question in the bot emulator:

1. Message sent to the bot.
2. Luis determines the proper intent; Emulator shows `Luis Trace` - looks exactly as I expect.
3. Emulator shows `QnAMaker Trace` with "*Unable to find a QnA Maker service with Knowledge Base ID [ID]. Please add a QnA Maker service to your bot.*"
4. **Bot returns the knowledgebase result exactly as I expect, despite the previous message in the trace.**

The trace is sent to the emulator after the following code executes in `MainDialog`.

```cs
var answers = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context, null, null);
```

I browsed through the locals while debugging, but did not see anything that stood out.

`Faq` knowledgebase is in the `cognitivemodels.json` with the form,

```
"knowledgebases": [
  {
    "name": "KB-NAME",
    "subscriptionKey": "SUBSCRIPTION KEY FROM AZURE COG SERVICE",
    "id": "KB-NAME",
    "hostname": "https://HOSTNAME.azurewebsites.net",
    "kbId": "KBID-FROM-QNAMAKER-SETTINGS-DEPLOYMENT-DETAILS",
    "endpointKey": "ENDPOINT-KEY-FROM-QNAMAKER-SETTINGS-DEPLOYMENT-DETIAILS"
  }
]
```

and `appsettings.json` has the following added in accordance with [this Microsoft example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker/appsettings.json)

```
"qnaMaker": {
    "endpoint": "ENDPOINT-FROM-AZURE-QNA-COG-RESOURCE",
    "key": "KEY-FROM-AZURE-QNA-COG-RESOURCE"
  },
  "QnAKnowledgebaseId": "KB-ID-FROM-QNAMAKER-SETTINGS-DEPLOYMENT-DETIAILS", // Also tried kb name from cogmodels.json
  "QnAAuthKey": "AUTH-ENDPOINT-KEY-FROM-QNAMAKER-SETTINGS-DEPLOYMENT-DETIAILS",
  "QnAEndpointHostName": "https://HOST.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker"
```

Am I overlooking something in my configuration details? The main source of my confusion is that ***it works as expected*** aside from the ominous trace that shows the QnA Maker service wasn't found.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. I get a similar message in the emulator when hitting LUIS (but only when it subsequently calls QnA Maker), but everything still works as expected. Here is the message I get: "Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."

Comment: @billoverton I was getting that in the past. Adding my app id/pass to the appsettings resolved it for me. I'll try publishing everything and seeing if it still works in a web chat. I'm not sure what the intent of the messages are if they don't truly mean anything, and the services still work as expected. Strange!

Comment: That could be a discrepancy for me...I don't have app ID/password set for local testing (though it is still hitting the LUIS and QnA Maker services on Azure).

Comment: your issue is similar to the ones reported before on GH https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1892 & https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case *you may have passed the wrong ID in your localhost* it was the problem for me.

check your `QNMakerBaseID` in your `bot configuration` in **azure**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your QnA info into *.bot file:

```
{
    "type": "qna",
    "endpointKey": "",
    "hostname": "",
    "id": "3",
    "kbId": "",
    "name": "",
    "subscriptionKey": ""
}
```

Then your in your Bot Framework Emulator you will see the details of the result coming from QnA

Comment: I think this is what I ended up doing, but it has been a while since I worked on this problem. Good point!